# Nativescript iOS app can't connect to a self-signed local domain

Tags: vue.js, axios, nativescript

I try to do a call to a local, self-signed https domain via axios on Nativescript, but it always gives "request failed with status code null" error. I discovered that I need to add the snippet below to allow unsecure URLs for iOS app.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
<dict>  
     <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>  
</dict>
```

I build the app again, using `tns platform clean ios`, but it still gives the same error. I can access the endpoint from either a seperate local Vue project or Postman. How can I fix it?

p.s: If I open the URL to public, it works, but the problem is I am depend on another API and it only work locally. So, I have to work locally somehow.

Comment: Are you hitting the local server by IP Or you have configured local domain name?

Comment: It's a local domain name.

Comment: You are using a self signed certificate which won't be trusted by your device unless you manually install it on your device. If you want to do it programatically, you will have to override the default NSURLSessionTaskDelegate in {N} http library.

Answer (score 1):

I had to install the root certificate on iOS simulator itself. I use Laravel's Valet for the API, so dragged and dropped `LaravelValetCASelfSigned.pem` file in CA folder of valet to the simulator and installed it. Then enabled it on General/Ceritificate Trust Settings and it worked.